# 12 halachic hours – why no more halachic consequences?

Tags: zemanim, shema, vilna-gaon

In MyZmanim (and other luachs) one can find the latest time for reading Shema according to the calculation of the Magen Avraham and Baal HaTanya / Gra. One can (and should) decide which approach to follow of the two. They arguing about which daytime to divide into 12 parts: from alot to tzeit (the broader one) or neitz to shekiya (the tighter one).

I wonder why their argument has rectifications on saying the morning Shema only? Seemingly this is a big machloket which should have bearings on all other halachic times, like saying Mincha, Maariv, accepting Shabbat, etc.

Comment: In fancy Luachs you can see it also for "end of eating chametz" times, for example.

Comment: @danny also for sof zman tefillah Shacharit, Mincha Gedolah, sof zman tefillah musaf, Mincha ketana, and plag

Comment: On MyZmanim you can see the Magen Avraham times for all of the daily times. Click All Zmainim at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument does indeed apply across the board.

Perhaps you see it discussed most about the last time for reciting Shema since that's the only time during the day with potential biblical consequences, leading some to be more stringent.